# How to create a list of many dataframes that have the same pattern of names?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

let's say I have these many dataset (let's imagine 1000 datasets) :

```
df1 = data.frame(x = 1:10)

df2 = data.frame(x = 2:11)

df3 = data.frame(x = 3:5)

df4 = data.frame(x = 11:20)
```

I want to create a list that is called L as follows

```
L = list(df1,df2,df3,df4)
```

but if I have thousands of dataframes, it would be difficult to write each dataframe namein the list. Would take forever. Would like a function that can make creating this list easier. Thanks.

Comment: Do the names of your data frames have a pattern? Did  they name sequantially like df1, df2, df3 so on?

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: `L = lapply(1:4, function(x) {get(paste0("df",x)) })`  where 4 is the maximum number at the end of your dataframes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you add your answer to the answer section so everyone can see the answer. Thanks again

Comment: How did you create those in the first place? It's better not to have a bunch of variables with indexes in their names. Think would be much easier if you created those related tables in a list to start with. While you can technically use `get()` or `mget()`, it's really a bad code smell in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `BaseR`,

```
n = 4
L = lapply(1:n, function(x) {get(paste0("df",x)) })
```

where **n** is the maximum number at the end of your dataframe names.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `get()` to extract data frames from their object name.

```
N <- 4
nms <- sprintf("df%i",1:N)
out <- list()
for(i in 1:N){
out[[i]] <- get(nms[i])  
}

out
```